# High performance computing and interconnects

Tags: programming-languages

High performance computing means different things to different people. From a pure programming perspective what I gather is that these are loads of individual machines connected by extremely fast interconnect not necessarily based on usual TCP/IP.

My question is on the interconnect side of things: How do you make interconnects faster without changing your socket based code much?

Comment: Give your machines a bigger pipe, say Fibre Channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TCP over just about any high-performance network. [OpenFabrics](http://www.openfabrics.org/) (a software stack for RDMA networks like InfiniBand and iWARP) has the "[sockets direct protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockets_Direct_Protocol)". Further, 10 GigE in all its forms was built specifically to provide compatibility with legacy socket code.

So feel free to use TCP on your high-performance network. It won't have the absolute best latency advantages compared to, say, using the underlying verbs. But it should be fast enough for most customers' needs.